# How do I compare the old data type value with the new ones

Tags: c#, json, linq, api, console-application

So I am using this [API](https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/) which shows the current price and other things when it comes to ethereum coins. And I'm trying to create a small console application that checks if the value has changed from the last time we scanned it.

What I have so far is this.. And I do know that I am scanning the current value with the current value so obviously its never going to change.
I tried setting a variable that would hold the old value but that didnt do anything.

How do I compare the first scan with the second one to see if the float value has gone up or down?

```
private static void Ticker()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                const string uri = @"https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/";
                var client = new WebClient();
                var content = client.DownloadString(uri);

                var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CoinApi>>(content);

                float currentAmount = results[0].price_usd;
                if (currentAmount < currentAmount)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Ammount is lower than the last time.");
                }
                else if (currentAmount > currentAmount)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The amount is higher than the last time.");
                }
                else if (currentAmount == currentAmount)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The amount hasnt changed since the last time we scanned.");
                }
            }
        }
```

And this is the class file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CryptoTicker.Core
{
    class Main
    {
    }

    public class CoinApi
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Symbol { get; set; }
        public float price_usd { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to remember the previous value. One way of doing this could be to maintain a dictionary of the id's and the CoinApi classes

```
public Dictionary<int, CoinApi> CoinDict = new Dictionary<int, CoinAPI>();
```

Then you can store the current values in this dictionary, and then compare the new values, against this existing values. And then update to the new values

```
public void UpdateCoinDict(CoinApi coin)
{
    CoinDict[coin.Id] = coin;
}

public float GetCoinPrice(CoinApi coin)
{
    if (CoinDict.Contains(coin.Id))
    {
        return CoinDict[coin.Id].price_usd;
    }
    else 
    {
        UpdateCoinDict(coin);
        return coin.price_usd;
    }              
}



private static void Ticker()
{
    while (true)
    {
        const string uri = @"https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/";
        var client = new WebClient();
        var content = client.DownloadString(uri);

        var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CoinApi>>(content);

        for (coin in results)
        {
            float currentAmount = coin.price_usd;
            float oldPrice = GetCoinPrice(coin); 
            if (currentAmount < oldPrice)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ammount is lower than the last time.");
            }
            else if (currentAmount > oldPrice)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The amount is higher than the last time.");
            }
            else
            {
            Console.WriteLine("The amount hasnt changed since the last time we scanned.");
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: My approach allows for handling several coin instances, if you only need to manage one price then other users have posted simpler approaches which may be more desirable

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the old value to a static variable should fix your problem. TODOS: What are you gonna do with your first request? Handle exceptions, etc...

Other issues: Should this run in `while(true)`? Maybe you should use a HttpClient and reuse it.

```
    private static float _oldValue;

    private static void Ticker()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            const string uri = @"https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/";
            var client = new WebClient();
            var content = client.DownloadString(uri);

            var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CoinApi>>(content);

            float currentAmount = results[0].price_usd;
            if (currentAmount < _oldValue)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ammount is lower than the last time.");
            }
            else if (currentAmount > _oldValue)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The amount is higher than the last time.");
            }
            else if (currentAmount == _oldValue)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The amount hasnt changed since the last time we scanned.");
            }

            _oldValue = currentAmount;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have written it, currentAmount will always be equal to itself.

This should work:

```
private static void Ticker()
{
    float previousAmount = 0.0;
    while (true)
    {
        const string uri = @"https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/";
        var client = new WebClient();
        var content = client.DownloadString(uri);

        var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CoinApi>>(content);

        float currentAmount = results[0].price_usd;

        if (currentAmount < previousAmount )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ammount is lower than the last time.");
        }
        else if (currentAmount > previousAmount )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The amount is higher than the last time.");
        }
        else if (currentAmount == previousAmount)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The amount hasnt changed since the last time we scanned.");
        }
        previousAmount = currentAmount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass previous execution value to the current execution to compare.
Declare that variable as in global score inside that class. Or declare it to the level up to where you want use it.